# Is it possible to make a pixel transparent using Windows Paint?

Tags: bitmap, icons, transparency, pixel, gimp

I have created an icon with round corners and I want the remaining part behind those round corners to be transparent (Not white) when I use it in windows.

Is it possible to do this just by using Windows 7 paint application? Or is there any simple trick or small application that can do this?

If there is no other way, how can I do this in Gimp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Paint, I don't know.

With Gimp,

1. Make a regular icon (square corners)
2. Make sure there is an alpha channel: `Layer > Transparency > Add alpha channel` (if its grayed it's already there)
3. Check `View > Snap to canvas edges`
4. Start the "Rectangle select" tool
5. Select the whole image (which is made easier by the snap setting in #3)
6. In the "Rectangle select" options, check `Rounded corners`, and adjust the roundness radius is the slider that appears below
7. [Enter] to "commit" the  selection when happy
8. `Select > Invert`
9. [Delete] or  `Edit > Clear`. You should now see the transparency checkerboard pattern in the corners.
10. Export to a transparent-capable format such as PNG

Comment: I did what you have said. I added an alpha channel then I exported it as a PNG file but it still has white dots around the corners

Comment: Ok, see revised answer...